# How to connect overlapping VNets in Azure?

Tags: networking, azure, azure-networking, virtual-network

I am working on an Azure-based networking solution.

[image]

We have a typical hub and spoke VNets topology. The Hub VNet connects to on-prem DC via ExpressRoute and spoke VNets peer to Hub VNet. There is an Azure Firewall in the Hub that filters traffic between Hub-spokes and hub-on-prem segments. GREEN in the diagram

We have a bizarre requirement of adding a new isolated VNet (RED in the diagram) that will have overlapping IPs with the existing network (GREEN). We want to allow workloads in this new VNet to access private apps deployed in Hub or on-prem.

I need help on how to achieve this connectivity.

**Note: We don't want to set up any VPN between the new VNet and Hub**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve what you want with any Azure networking services as they all require non overlapping IP ranges.